# In ARKIT using unity how to place the models in only one specific direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

New to unity and ARKIT.I have tried my project using Focussquare.It detects a plane and when I touch on the screen device it place the model on that position.The problem is every time I touch when starting the app the models would be in different orientation.That is sometimes model will be facing me otherwise it will be will turned in different position.I am not talking about flipping but it faces different positions.I need in such a way that the model should face me all the time or any other direction but only in one direction.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

namespace UnityEngine.XR.iOS
{
public class UnityARHitTestExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject hidesquare;

    public GameObject hidetoast;



    public Camera playerCamera;

    private float distance = 3.0f;

    public Transform m_HitTransform;





    public float maxRayDistance = 30.0f;
    public GameObject lockobject;
    public LayerMask collisionLayer = 1 << 10;  //ARKitPlane layer



    bool HitTestWithResultType(ARPoint point, ARHitTestResultType resultTypes)
    {
        List<ARHitTestResult> hitResults = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface().HitTest(point, resultTypes);
        if (hitResults.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var hitResult in hitResults)
            {
                Debug.Log("Got hit!");
                hidesquare.SetActive(false);
                hidetoast.SetActive(false);

                lockobject.GetComponent<UnityARHitTestExample>().enabled = false;
                m_HitTransform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);


                m_HitTransform.position = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition(hitResult.localTransform);
                m_HitTransform.rotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation(hitResult.localTransform);


                m_HitTransform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform.position);
                m_HitTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, m_HitTransform.eulerAngles.y, 0);


                Debug.Log(string.Format("x:{0:0.######} y:{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", m_HitTransform.position.x, m_HitTransform.position.y, m_HitTransform.position.z));
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    //private bool IsPointerOverUIObject()
    //{
    //    PointerEventData eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
    //    eventDataCurrentPosition.position = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    //    List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    //    EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);
    //    return results.Count > 0;
    //}


    //bool IsPointerOverGameObject(int fingerId)
    //{
    //    EventSystem eventSystem = EventSystem.current;
    //    return (eventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject(fingerId)
    //        && eventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject != null);
    //}

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR   //we will only use this script on the editor side, though there is nothing that would prevent it from working on device
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            //we'll try to hit one of the plane collider gameobjects that were generated by the plugin
            //effectively similar to calling HitTest with ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxRayDistance, collisionLayer))
            {
                //we're going to get the position from the contact point
                m_HitTransform.position = hit.point;
                Debug.Log(string.Format("x:{0:0.######} y:{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", m_HitTransform.position.x, m_HitTransform.position.y, m_HitTransform.position.z));

                //and the rotation from the transform of the plane collider
                m_HitTransform.rotation = hit.transform.rotation;
            }
        }
#else
        if (Input.touchCount == 1 && m_HitTransform != null)
        {

            var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if ((touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))

            {
                //hidebtn.SetActive(false);
               // this.transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                var screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
                ARPoint point = new ARPoint
                {
                    x = screenPosition.x,
                    y = screenPosition.y
                };

                // prioritize reults types
                ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = 
                {
                    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent, 
                    // if you want to use infinite planes use this:
                    //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
                    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeHorizontalPlane, 
                    ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
                }; 

                foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType in resultTypes)
                {
                    if (HitTestWithResultType (point, resultType))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

#endif
    }
}
```

}

I tried with foundSquare.transform.position and foundSquare.transform.rotation changing their position and rotation to camera transform but did not work.

[image: Hierarachy using both Hitcube and focussquare]

Comment: Have you tried `Transform.LookAt(Transform)`?

Comment: Yes,previous comment got deleted..he gave the same opinion.I tried.When I touch the screen the model gets placed facing forward with respect to y-axis.Next time when I open my app then it gets placed right ,left or forward with respect to y-axis.I want the model to get placed only in one direction say facing forward.This is an AR application that is why the camera lookat is not working?

Comment: Are you using the vector direction from the plane, as the vector direction of your instantiate prefab?

Comment: Well, the `LookAt` has noting to do with AR application. However I'm struggling to understand what is exactly your desired behavior. If you say its fine that the model is facing the camera (the phone), that means every time you place another object (no mater where you place it) its still going to face you. Imagine it like two speakers that are like 1 meter apart but both facing you. Is that what you want? or you want them both facing foreword?

Comment: @Lotan how will i know that

Comment: @Hristo Everytime it doesnt face my camera.It place the models in random rotations in y axis.

Comment: with this.transform.up, forward, etc https://answers.unity.com/questions/211910/getting-object-local-direction.html